# How to download two different files in powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have this simple script that is working and I'm able to download a csv file From my SharePoint site but I'm just wondering how can I modify it so that I can download another file that is located in another path and save it in the same local folder as soon as the first one is complete downloading?.

Basically this is what I'm trying to do

```
Download this first
$SourceFile="/sites/msteams/ReportsFull/OneDrive.csv"

Download this second, save in the same folder with the first one
$SourceFile="/sites/msteams/Shared%20Documents/OneDriveInventory/ActiveLitHoldWithOneDrive.csv"
```

```
\#Set parameter values
$SiteURL="https://companyName.sharepoint.com"

$SourceFile="/sites/msteams/ReportsFull/OneDrive.csv"
$TargetFile="C:\\Users\\AS\\Downloads\\New folder\\LegalDoc.docx"

Function Download-FileFromLibrary()
{
param
(
\[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)\] \[string\] $SiteURL,
\[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)\] \[string\] $SourceFile,
\[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)\] \[string\] $TargetFile
)

    Try {
        #Setup Credentials to connect
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Global:adminUPN, $Global:adminPwd)
    
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
     
        #sharepoint online powershell download file from library
        $FileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($Ctx,$SourceFile)
        $WriteStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($TargetFile,[System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
        $FileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($WriteStream)
        $WriteStream.Close()
    
        Write-host -f Green "File '$SourceFile' Downloaded to '$TargetFile' Successfully!" $_.Exception.Message

}
Catch {
write-host -f Red "Error Downloading File!" $\_.Exception.Message
}
}

\#Call the function to download file
Download-FileFromLibrary -SiteURL $SiteURL -SourceFile $SourceFile -TargetFile $TargetFile
```

Comment: if you simply just make another call to `Download-FileFromLibrary`, PowerShell reads the code top to bottom and will execute it accordingly.

Comment: What is the meaning of all those backslashes in the parameter block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right code, just need to call the function twice

````
$sourceFile1 = '/sites/msteams/ReportsFull/OneDrive.csv'
$targetFile1 = 'C:\\Users\\AS\\Downloads\\New folder\\LegalDoc.docx'
Download-FileFromLibrary -SiteURL $SiteURL -SourceFile $SourceFile1 -TargetFile $TargetFile1

$sourceFile2 = '/sites/msteams/Shared%20Documents/OneDriveInventory/ActiveLitHoldWithOneDrive.csv'
$targetFile2 = 'C:\\Users\\AS\\Downloads\\New Folder\\NewFile2.docx'
Download-FileFromLibrary -SiteURL $siteUrl -SourceFile $sourceFile2 -TargetFile $targetFile2```
````